# Calling action in PHP file inline with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm really out of practice on my JS and I'm trying to incorporate a "delete" mechanism into some existing code that displays rows of data. If it were straight PHP I'd have no problem but it's got some JQuery and other random JS stuff. Here's the code:

```
<?php

require_once '../../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');

$date = date('Y-m-d');

$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');

$current = $read->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM offers WHERE end_date >= '".$date."' OR end_date = '0000-00-00' ORDER BY end_date DESC");
$old = $read->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM offers WHERE end_date < '".$date."' AND end_date not like '0000-00-00' ORDER BY end_date DESC");

$read->closeConnection();

?>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #ece9e6;
    }
    .container {
        background: white;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(51,44,38,0.1);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(51,44,38,0.1);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(51,44,38,0.1);
        margin: 0px auto;
        padding: 40px;
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
    h1 {
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    .add-new {
        display: none;
        width: 275px;
        margin: 10px auto;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Offers</h1>
        <p style="text-align:center;"><a href="#" id="addNew" style="color:#9a9a9a;">+ Add New Offer</a></p>
        <div class="add-new">
            <form id="add-new-form">
            Offer Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/><br>
            Offer Description: <input type="text" name="description" id="description"/><br>
            Start Date: <input type="text" name="start-date" id="start-date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"/><br>
            End Date: <input type="text" name="end-date" id="end-date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"/><br>
            Coupon Code: <input type="text" name="coupon-code" id="coupon-code" /><br>
            Special Code: <input type="text" name="posoe-code" id="posoe-code" /><br>
            <p style="font-size: 0.8em; font-style:italic; padding:10px; margin-bottom:3px;">
                POWPromo - Product of the Week<br>
                FLASHPromo - Flash Sale<br>
                NWSLTRPromo - Newsletter Offer<br>
                HOLIDAYPromo - Holiday Promo<br>
                SUBSCPromo - New Newsletter Subscriber Promo<br>
                20-150Promo - $20 Off $50 Promo
            </p>
            Fine Print: <textarea name="fine_print" id="fine-print"></textarea><br>
            Order Minimum: <input type="text" name="order_minimum" id="order-minimum" />
            Shipping Coupon? <input type="radio" name="shipping_coupon" value="1"/> Yes &nbsp; <input type="radio" name="shipping_coupon" value="0" checked="checked"/> No<br>
            Password: <input type="text" name="password" id="password"/><br>
            </form>
            <p style="color:red; font-weight;bold; display:none;" id="error">Invalid Password.</p>
            <button class="btn btn-default submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="span12">
            <h2 style="color:green;">Current Offers</h2>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <tr class="bg-success">
                    <th>Offer</th>
                    <th>Start Date</th>
                    <th>End Date</th>
                    <th>Coupon Code</th>
                    <th>Special Code</th>
                </tr>
                <?php foreach ($current as $c) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:50%;">
                            <p style="font-size:1.2em;"><b><?php echo $c['name']; ?></b></p>
                            <p style="font-size: 0.9em; line-height:18px;"><?php echo $c['description']; ?></p>
                            <?php if ($c['fine_print'] != '') { ?>
                                <p style="font-size: 0.7em; line-height:14px; font-style:italic; color:#9a9a9a;"><b>Fine Print: </b><?php echo $c['fine_print']; ?></p>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($c['start_date'])); ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php if ($c['end_date'] == '0000-00-00') { ?>
                                <i>Varies</i>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <?php echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($c['end_date'])); ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php if ($c['coupon_code'] == '') { ?>
                                <i>Varies</i>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <?php echo $c['coupon_code']; ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $c['special_code']; ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <h2 style="color:red;">Expired Offers</h2>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <tr class="bg-danger">
                    <th>Offer</th>
                    <th>Start Date</th>
                    <th>End Date</th>
                    <th>Coupon Code</th>
                    <th>Special Code</th>
                </tr>
                <?php foreach ($old as $o) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:50%;">
                            <p style="font-size:1.2em;"><b><?php echo $o['name']; ?></b></p>
                            <p style="font-size: 0.9em; line-height:18px;"><?php echo $o['description']; ?></p>
                            <?php if ($o['fine_print'] != '') { ?>
                                <p style="font-size: 0.7em; line-height:14px; font-style:italic; color:#9a9a9a;"><b>Fine Print: </b><?php echo $o['fine_print']; ?></p>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($o['start_date'])); ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($o['end_date'])); ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $o['coupon_code']; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $o['special_code']; ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('click', '#addNew', function() {
        $('.add-new').toggle();
    });

    $('.submit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#error').hide();
        if ($('#password').val() == 'somepassword') {
            $.ajax({ 
                url:'add.php', 
                type:'POST', 
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    name: $('#name').val(),
                    description: $('#description').val(),
                    start_date: $('#start-date').val(),
                    end_date: $('#end-date').val(),
                    coupon_code: $('#coupon-code').val(),
                    posoe_code: $('#special-code').val(),
                    fine_print: $('#fine-print').val(),
                    order_minimum: $('#order-minimum').val(),
                    shipping_coupon: $('input[name="shipping_coupon"]').val()
                }, 
                success:function(data) {
                    location.reload();
                } 
            });
        } else {
            $('#error').show();
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

So, if that hasn't scared you off, what I need to do is call a "delete.php" on every row via a button or anchor link. Seems like I should enumerate the rows somehow so that said link has an identifier (like , etc.), and perhaps I could use innerhtml to read what is in those id's. But do I create a function and assign it to an anchor for the actual delete button? Or do I compose the action in-line with each individual button somehow? Probably a lot to ask either way!

The PHP file I'm calling looks like this:

```
<?php

    require_once '../../app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app('default');

    // Delete offer
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $name = Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($_POST['name']);
        $coupon_code = Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($_POST['coupon_code']);
        $posoe_code = Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($_POST['posoe_code']);

        $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

        if ($coupon_code == 'Varies') {
            $write->query("DELETE FROM offers WHERE name = '".$name."', special_code = '".$special_code."'");       
        } else {
            $write->query("DELETE FROM offers WHERE name = '".$name."', coupon_code = '".$coupon_code."', special_code = '".$special_code."'"); 
        }

        $write->query("DELETE FROM coupon_reject_reason WHERE coupon_code = '".$coupon_code."'");

        $write->query("DELETE FROM special_codes WHERE coupon_code = '".$coupon_code."', special_code = '".$special_code."'");

        $write->closeConnection();
    }

    $result['success'] = true;

    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Nothing surprising there. If you're familiar with Magento at all (The Mage parts) you know that I'm accessing it's DB functionality to run the queries. Though there might be a better way than using $write->. That's not the issue though. The real problem is with the Ajax up top.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, you need to enclose the `data` values in quotes in the Ajax for your submit button.

Comment: Your code is **wide open** to SQL injection attacks.  You **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  It's critical to use parameterized queries with PDO or similar.

Comment: This is used on an internal network, unconnected to any Internet-facing routers. It's a private system that only a few people have access to and they are most definitely not interested in hacking. Of course you are correct though, if I were to put this on an open network it would likely be exploited in short order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ajax at the top is for submitting the form and calling add.php, but you want an Ajax that calls delete.php. Since you've already written the first Ajax, you should know how to write the second Ajax. So will not touch that part, and will only answer your questions.

> what I need to do is call a "delete.php" on every row via a button or anchor link.

Bothe will work. However, if you go with links, you've got to cancel their default behavior like you did with the `submit` button using `e.preventDefault();` in the `click` event.

> Seems like I should enumerate the rows somehow so that said link has an identifier (like , etc.), and perhaps I could use innerhtml to read what is in those id's.

You can do that, but I would store the ID in a `data-id` attribute of each link. Something like:

```
<a class="delete" href="#" data-id="<?php echo $c['id'];?>">Delete</a>
```

and then get the value of the attribute like this:

```
$(this).data("id");
```

> But do I create a function and assign it to an anchor for the actual delete button?

I would create one event listener for all the delete buttons and inside I can access the current button using `this`:

```
$(".delete").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    //$.Ajax...
});
```

Comment: Never concatenate data directly into HTML.  Always use `htmlspecialchars()` or equivalent, to escape the data properly.

Comment: @Brad Completely agree, but that's only required for string values. I assume the ID is an integer, and that doesn't require escaping. Even if it is a string, it cannot be coming from user input or untrusted source, so again it doesn't require escaping. If none of that is true, then there is a much more serious problem to deal with. So your comment is good for the OP, but not required for my answer.

Comment: Just to clarify, I didn't write this code. I'm just taking over for the programmer who did and they aren't available to ask questions of. That said, your explanation of what needs done makes some sense. I'll play with it some more. I appreciate the response.

Comment: No, you're wrong.  Your ID might be an integer today, but it could change in the future and this bit of code would be missed because it's expected that something inserting data into HTML does it transparently.  Furthermore, the idea that escaping is simply a security issue is incorrect.  You might have some real non-user data that has reserved characters such as `<` or `>`.  If you don't escape it, you could end up with broken HTML

Comment: @brad I didn't say the escaping was only for security. I said it is only required for string values. Numeric values do not have reserved characters and do not pose any security risk, hence do not require escaping. An ID should not have special characters, but if it does, then yes it will require escaping. However, I would not escape everything just in case they change. Escaping is an expensive operation and when you change the data type of a field, you cannot expect your app to just continue working. You **MUST** review all related code.

Comment: @Brad By the way, changing the type of a field is not a small change, especially if the field is an ID. It requires careful code review like I said, but also regression and security testing. If you don't have those testers on your team, then your team's got a problem. And if you have them and they still miss such an obvious spot, then the project manager should be actively looking for a replacement for those team members :).

Comment: @RacilHilan Escaping is not an expensive operation.  Your approach to software development is very poor.  You must maintain abstraction at appropriate layers.  Your attitude towards this problem is why we have so many security bugs.  For the sake of everyone who has to use the code you write, please reconsider your thoughts on the matter.

Comment: @Brad Your comment is unnecessarily offensive. Try expressing your thoughts with respect. 1) Escaping looks for special chars, it has a cost. 2) Escaping everything just in case of future changes violates YAGNI and continuous refactoring&integration principles. When have you changed the ID type last time? 3) Abstraction of layers is irrelevant, the rules are only in the UI layer. You can read [MS guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx) as an example. You may choose not to follow the guidelines, but that doesn't make them *very poor and have so many security bugs*.

Comment: @RacilHilan Of course everything has a cost.  You know, when I'm buying a house, I usually don't worry about checking to see if the 50-cent lightbulb will be included at closing.  When I'm writing code, interpreted code, PHP code, PHP code for the web of all things, throwing out important context adaptation is at the bottom of my list for things to optimize.  YAGNI is irrelevant here... what you've created is straight up, a bug.  It *will* bite you some day, as it has bitten many others.  Rather than getting offended, you should take the time to revisit your thoughts on the issue.

Comment: Obviously listening, accepting, and respecting other views is not important here. I referenced the MS guidelines for best practice, but it seems nobody else's opinion matters. Escaping everything is certainly good for developers who don't want to think, and prefer to pay the cost. I prefer to use my brain, and will keep waiting for the bugs to come and bite as they haven't shown up in the past 20 years. I revisit my thoughts on real issues, not issues that don't exist like escaping an integer ID that may change when my grand-grandson starts working on the code while I'm pushing up daisies.